# How to get image source and description from html data using Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am trying to parse atom feeds to extract feeds using ROME API. the atom feed gives me content attribute which contains an image and description of the article.
Here's the url of atom feed: https://news.google.com/news/section?output=atom&ned=in&q=narendra%20modi.
Now I want to extract image and description from the content part.

```
 <entry>
<id>tag:news.google.com,2005:cluster=http://www.ndtv.com/india-news/not-just-gst-stuck-in-parliament-matter-of-sorrow-pm-narendra-modi-1253222</id>
<title type="html">'Not Just GST Stuck In Parliament. Matter of Sorrow': PM Narendra Modi - NDTV</title>
<updated>2015-12-10T06:03:54Z</updated>
<link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;fd=R&amp;ct2=in&amp;usg=AFQjCNE53SQd2skoJLxBTVlYWHdgDBCl7Q&amp;clid=c3a7d30bb8a4878e06b80cf16b898331&amp;cid=52779006372283&amp;ei=ACdpVoDJO9Sj4ALYkL94&amp;url=http://www.ndtv.com/india-news/not-just-gst-stuck-in-parliament-matter-of-sorrow-pm-narendra-modi-1253222" hreflang="en"/>
<content type="html">&lt;table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="7" style="vertical-align:top;">&lt;tr>&lt;td width="80" align="center" valign="top">&lt;font style="font-size:85%;font-family:arial,sans-serif">&lt;a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;amp;fd=R&amp;amp;ct2=in&amp;amp;usg=AFQjCNE53SQd2skoJLxBTVlYWHdgDBCl7Q&amp;amp;clid=c3a7d30bb8a4878e06b80cf16b898331&amp;amp;cid=52779006372283&amp;amp;ei=ACdpVoDJO9Sj4ALYkL94&amp;amp;url=http://www.ndtv.com/india-news/not-just-gst-stuck-in-parliament-matter-of-sorrow-pm-narendra-modi-1253222">&lt;img src="//t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSNi4SJFo9q9PXKPOjJkiUlfk2GFRzRoBlwK6UsiSQ8np66JDvgQiYTdN4Fknntb7bVjdR-NuM" alt="" border="1" width="80" height="80">&lt;br>&lt;font size="-2">NDTV&lt;/font>&lt;/a>&lt;/font>&lt;/td>&lt;td valign="top" class="j">&lt;font style="font-size:85%;font-family:arial,sans-serif">&lt;br>&lt;div style="padding-top:0.8em;">&lt;img alt="" height="1" width="1">&lt;/div>&lt;div class="lh">&lt;a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;amp;fd=R&amp;amp;ct2=in&amp;amp;usg=AFQjCNE53SQd2skoJLxBTVlYWHdgDBCl7Q&amp;amp;clid=c3a7d30bb8a4878e06b80cf16b898331&amp;amp;cid=52779006372283&amp;amp;ei=ACdpVoDJO9Sj4ALYkL94&amp;amp;url=http://www.ndtv.com/india-news/not-just-gst-stuck-in-parliament-matter-of-sorrow-pm-narendra-modi-1253222">&lt;b>&amp;#39;Not Just GST Stuck In Parliament. Matter of Sorrow&amp;#39;: PM &lt;b>Narendra Modi&lt;/b>&lt;/b>&lt;/a>&lt;br>&lt;font size="-1">&lt;b>&lt;font color="#6f6f6f">NDTV&lt;/font>&lt;/b>&lt;/font>&lt;br>&lt;font size="-1">With repeated disruptions stalling legislation including the GST or Goods and Services Tax, Prime Minister &lt;b>Narendra Modi&lt;/b> today said it was a &amp;quot;matter of sorrow&amp;quot; that Parliament was not running. &amp;quot;It is not only GST, but many pro-poor steps are stuck in&amp;nbsp;...&lt;/font>&lt;br>&lt;font size="-1">&lt;a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;amp;fd=R&amp;amp;ct2=in&amp;amp;usg=AFQjCNEVhO7UtISsITzRIFwxTVFwK8BTDQ&amp;amp;clid=c3a7d30bb8a4878e06b80cf16b898331&amp;amp;cid=52779006372283&amp;amp;ei=ACdpVoDJO9Sj4ALYkL94&amp;amp;url=http://www.india.com/news/india/narendra-modis-stern-message-to-congress-democracy-cannot-run-on-whims-of-some-773082/">&lt;b>Narendra Modi&amp;#39;s&lt;/b> stern message to Congress: Democracy cannot run on whims of some&lt;/a>&lt;font size="-1" color="#6f6f6f">&lt;nobr>India.com&lt;/nobr>&lt;/font>&lt;/font>&lt;br>&lt;font size="-1">&lt;a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;amp;fd=R&amp;amp;ct2=in&amp;amp;usg=AFQjCNGkBqqpn2OhEI6w68lLCIXMDppu-Q&amp;amp;clid=c3a7d30bb8a4878e06b80cf16b898331&amp;amp;cid=52779006372283&amp;amp;ei=ACdpVoDJO9Sj4ALYkL94&amp;amp;url=http://www.mid-day.com/articles/jagran-forum-catch-pm-narendra-modi-other-leaders-live/16757192">Jagran Forum: Catch PM &lt;b>Narendra Modi&lt;/b>, other leaders live&lt;/a>&lt;font size="-1" color="#6f6f6f">&lt;nobr>Mid-Day&lt;/nobr>&lt;/font>&lt;/font>&lt;br>&lt;font size="-1">&lt;a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;amp;fd=R&amp;amp;ct2=in&amp;amp;usg=AFQjCNHPkB8Wy_-cDqqZrdfcn1cVUKP-Kg&amp;amp;clid=c3a7d30bb8a4878e06b80cf16b898331&amp;amp;cid=52779006372283&amp;amp;ei=ACdpVoDJO9Sj4ALYkL94&amp;amp;url=http://www.oneindia.com/india/democracy-cant-be-restricted-to-elections-only-narendra-modi-1951641.html">Democracy can&amp;#39;t be restricted to elections only, says &lt;b>Narendra Modi&lt;/b>&lt;/a>&lt;font size="-1" color="#6f6f6f">&lt;nobr>Oneindia&lt;/nobr>&lt;/font>&lt;/font>&lt;br>&lt;font size="-1" class="p">&lt;a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;amp;fd=R&amp;amp;ct2=in&amp;amp;usg=AFQjCNFhxDKEsImpQqu0GccMt4MCiPydVw&amp;amp;clid=c3a7d30bb8a4878e06b80cf16b898331&amp;amp;cid=52779006372283&amp;amp;ei=ACdpVoDJO9Sj4ALYkL94&amp;amp;url=http://www.abplive.in/india-news/everyone-must-feel-he-or-she-is-working-for-indias-progress-says-narendra-modi-258229">&lt;nobr>ABP Live&lt;/nobr>&lt;/a>&lt;/font>&lt;br>&lt;font class="p" size="-1">&lt;a class="p" href="http://news.google.com/news/more?ncl=dac7xEJd70rfdkM8gcjOwSJn8BK9M&amp;amp;authuser=0&amp;amp;ned=in">&lt;nobr>&lt;b>all 29 news articles&amp;nbsp;&amp;raquo;&lt;/b>&lt;/nobr>&lt;/a>&lt;/font>&lt;/div>&lt;/font>&lt;/td>&lt;/tr>&lt;/table></content>
</entry>
```

For image i have tried the following code of jsoup:

```
Elements img = doc.getElementsByTag("img");
         for (Element el : img) {
             System.out.println("Image Found!");
             System.out.println("src attribute is : "+el.attr("src"));
         }
```

But it returns nothing. Also i don't know how to proceed on extracting the description:

```
&lt;br>&lt;font size="-1">NEW DELHI: Putting the Ufa process back on track India and Pakistan on Wednesday signaled process of reducing tensions by announcing Comprehensive Bilateral Dialogue to be led by Foreign Secretaries and prepared the ground for a visit by Prime&amp;nbsp;...&lt;/font>
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: You may use ROME to extract the entries (or use jackson with xml plugin). Then get the HTML content of every entry and parse it using jsoup (convert &lt; and &gt; beforehand). Then use the return HTML Element and search for the img-tag to extract the src-attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Please note that the RSS feed is fetched with Jsoup directly.

```
Document news = Jsoup.connect("http://news.google.com/news/section?output=atom&ned=in&q=narendra%20modi").get();

int i=0;
for (Element entryContent : news.select("entry > content")) {
    System.out.format("\n## ENTRY %d\n", ++i);
    for (Element el : Jsoup.parse(entryContent.text()).select("img[src], tr td.j font[size]:nth-of-type(2)")) {

        String elementTagName = el.tagName();  

        if (elementTagName.equalsIgnoreCase("img")) {
            System.out.println("src attribute is : " + el.attr("src"));
        } else if (elementTagName.equalsIgnoreCase("font")) {
            System.out.println("description is : " + el.text());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Unexpected element >> " + el.html());
        }
    }
}
```

#### SAMPLE OUTPUT

```
## ENTRY 1
src attribute is : //t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSLee4ulBtCEOMSuDuLHCAjDZwmlaVaXJVdC09133QbK3X1OpZH3s1RBplznEadxqV5memM0dh3
description is : With repeated disruptions stalling legislation including the GST or Goods and Services Tax, Prime Minister Narendra Modi today said it was a "matter of sorrow" that Parliament was not running. "It is not only GST, but many pro-poor steps are stuck in ...

## ENTRY 2
src attribute is : //t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQdJPtLOBi9F2Ktov11_x5kqHC4inID47xKD3we_ZC5rHP1Lps96sYHs_N0pBO9WkDj5KKuEa8
description is : Prime Minister Narendra Modi topped the charts of Facebook under the most-viewed

(...)
```

**Tested on JSoup 1.8.3**

Comment: Running your code gives me this exception:    Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.UnsupportedMimeTypeException: Unhandled content type. Must be text/*, application/xml, or application/xhtml+xml. Mimetype=application/atom+xml, URL=http://news.google.com/news/section?output=atom&ned=in&q=narendra%20modi
 at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:472)
 at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:424)
 at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:178)
 at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:167)

Comment: @GarimaTripathi Which version of JSoup are you using?

Comment: @GarimaTripathi Alternatively, you can call `ignoreContentType(true)` to work around this issue. So news can be downloaded like this: `Document news = Jsoup.connect("http://news.google.com/news/section?output=atom&ned=in&q=narendra%20modi").ignoreContentType(true).get();`